# im tryin to make it so when you touch a part, it becomes transparent and when it becomes transparent it will become completely invisible

Tags: lua, roblox

```
local e = "asdusad"
    game.Workspace.Part.Touched:Connect(function()
        game.Workspace.Part.Transparency = .7
        if game.Workspace.Part.Transparency == .7 then
            e = true
            if e == true then 
                game.Workspace.Part.Transparency = 1
            elseif e == false then
                game.Workspace.Part.Transparency = 0
            end
        end
    end)
```

in roblox studio, it doesnt show that theres any errors but it doesnt work

Comment: You tagged this with 4 different languages - why? The code does not resemble SQL, C or R.

Comment: ok nvm i just mistaken myself thought i had to have 5 tags

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying to do? In the future, you should try to add more information than just the title and your code. Do you want it to become more transparent every time you touch it? Or do you want it to start fading out once you touch it the first time?

Answer (score 0):

```
local e = "asdusad"
game.Workspace.Part.Touched:Connect(function()
    game.Workspace.Part.Transparency = .7
    if game.Workspace.Part.Transparency == .7 then
        e = true
        if e == true then 
            game.Workspace.Part.Transparency = 1
        elseif e == false then
            game.Workspace.Part.Transparency = 0
        end
    end
 end)
```

How does this code make any sense logic-wise?

You assign `game.Workspace.Part.Transparency = .7`.

Then `if game.Workspace.Part.Transparency == .7` (which is always true because you just assigned that value) you assign `e = true` and after that `if e == true` (which again is always true as you assigned that value) you assign `game.Workspace.Part.Transparency = 1`.

This code is equivalent to:

```
local e = "asdusad"
game.Workspace.Part.Touched:Connect(function()
   e = true
   game.Workspace.Part.Transparency = 1
end)
```

Everytime this event handler is triggered you make the object opaque.

You need to only make it transparent if it is opaque and make it opaque only if it transparent.

Comment: ohhh wow i just made the code more complicated than it should be

Comment: no you broke the logic.